# Сравнение типов данных в C# switch

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Здраствуйте, есть задание сравнить объект, который имеет определенный тип используя только метод switch. Можете объяснить как делать такое сравнение используя только switch. (C# новый для меня язык программирования, и поэтому не могу понять логику как сравнивать)

```
Gets the message with information about the type of integer in format:
        /// - "{arg} is sbyte.", if arg is sbyte;
        /// - "{arg} is byte.", if arg is byte;
        /// - "{arg} is short.", if arg is short;
        /// - "{arg} is int.", if arg is int;
        /// - "{arg} is long.", if arg is long;
        /// - "{arg} is ushort.", if arg is ushort;
        /// - "{arg} is uint.", if arg is uint;
        /// - "{arg} is ulong.", if arg is ulong.
        /// - "{arg} is not integer.", otherwise.      
 public static string GetType(object arg)
    {
        switch (arg.GetType())
        {
            case typeof(sbyte arg):
                return $"{arg} is sbyte.";
                break;
        }
```

Comment: А что вам мешает открыть документацию и глянуть как он используется? Вам ведь тут не нужна какая-либо логика, простое использование стандартной конструкции, с перечислением всех типов, не более.

Comment: До этого уже делал задания с switch но именно на сравнений типов данных программа выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? Где ваши попытки вообще в вопросе?

Comment: public static string GetType(object arg)
        {
            switch (arg.GetType())
            {
                case typeof(sbyte arg):
                    return $"{arg} is sbyte.";
                    break;

Comment: [Кхм...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUuc0x), [Кхммм...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6aj1U)..

Comment: Ошибка CS8400 - это уже вопрос тогда  с установкой .net 5

Comment: Я вам дал 2 ссылки, где стандартный `switch` и нет. Если у вас проект старый (что зря), используйте старые решения. Главное, вы я надеюсь ошибку свою поняли...

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксис немного другой

```cs
switch (arg)
{
    case sbyte:
        return $"{arg} is sbyte.";
    case int:
        return $"{arg} is int.";
}
```

Но еще лучше использовать актульный фреймворк, а не устаревший тогда вам подойдут решения из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching).